# parity flag getting mixed results with "one and zero"

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

Check this code out

```
include 'win32ax.inc'

;.data


.code

start:

mov al,00000001b

add al,00000001b   ;even  =2     pf = 0
add al,00000001b   ;odd   =3     pf = 1
add al,00000001b   ;even  =4     pf = 0
sub al,00000001b   ;odd   =3     pf = 1
sub al,00000001b   ;even  =2     pf = 0
sub al,00000001b   ;odd   =1     pf = 0
sub al,00000001b   ;even  =0     pf = 1

.end start
```

The last two subtraction instructions should of set PF=1, then PF=0, so why doesn't it?

Also i'm using FASM, i'm debugging with ollydbg debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from wikipedia:

In x86 processors, the parity flag reflects the parity only of the least significant byte of the result, and is set if the number of set bits of ones is even.

so

```
result = 0  an even number of ones are set so pf = 1 is the right answer
result = 1 an odd number of ones are set so pf = 0 is the right answer
result = 2 an odd number of ones are set so pf = 0 is the right answer
result = 3 an even number of ones are set so pf = 1 is the right answer

1 = 0b00000001  one bit is set an odd number of bits set pf = 0
3 = 0b00000011 two bits are set pf = 1
7 = 0b00000111 three bits are set pf = 0
12 = 0b00001100 two bits are set pf = 1
```

Comment: well heres my confusion

Comment: sub al,00000001b   ;odd   =3     pf = 1                             sub al,00000001b   ;odd   =1     pf = 0

Comment: they are both odd but have different results, if it's 3 then PF=1, if it's 1 PF=0

Comment: actually im still confused

Comment: PF is set, when the number of 1s is even or zero. 0: 0000 PF=1 // 1: 0001 PF=0 // 2: 0010 PF=0 // 3: 0011 PF=1 // 4: 0100 PF=0. Thus it is only set if the result is 0 and 3 in your example.

Comment: when my eax register says 7742D303 PF = 1, when my eax register says 7742D301 PF = 0? I haven't read your comment yet blechdose you posted before me

Comment: yeah, should be. In your case, your mistake is to look at the decimal number odd/eveness, instead of looking at the dualcode itself. Be carefull, that is different from the Paritybits used in ASCII and so on.

Comment: I'm going to go back and mess around with my code for a bit so this can sink in better

Comment: yeah, the problem is, that debugger show hexnumbers, that can be quite confusing, when you think about stuff like parity bit, signumflag and stuff like that. I had moments like that, too, until i finally checked out the dualcode of the result

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what i was doing, i was looking at what number the bits represented instead of counting how many bits were turned on. No wonder i was confused. Thanks everyone for the help i can't thank you enough.